# Error using an Interface as a return type [Java]

Tags: java, interface

I've these two Java interfaces:

the first one is:

```
public abstract interface A {

}
```

and the second one is:

```
public abstract interface B {
    public abstract Set<A> methodName();
}
```

Then, I've implemented these two interfaces as:

```
public class AImpl implements A {

}
```

and:

```
public class BImpl implements B {
    private Set<AImpl> p;  

    public Set<A> methodName() {
        return this.p;
    }
}
```

I don't understand why I obtain the following error about the implementation of methodName():

```
Type mismatch: cannot convert from Set<AImpl> to Set<A>
```

Thank you very much.

Comment: Interfaces in java are always abstract, no need to declare them explicitly

Answer (score 6):

`Set<AImpl>` is not exactly the same what `Set<A>`, you cannot convert it.
You can:

- declare p as `Set<A>`
- declare p as `Set<? extends A>`
- return `Set<AImpl>`    in `methodName()`

More details:
if `AImpl` implements/extends A then `List<AImpl>` does not implement/extend `List<A>`.
`List<? extends A>` means that this is the list of something that extends/implements A.

Look at [Wildcards and subtyping in Java Tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/subtyping.html)

Comment: Thank you very much Patryk. The curious thing is that inside B there is another method that has as return type another interface but in this case there isn't nobody problem. The problem is that this is an university assignment so I can't change the interface (it's given by the lecturer)

Answer (score 2):

To add something in `Patryk Dobrowolski's` *answer*

Here problem is `Set<Car>` is different than `Set<Vehicle>` note here that `Car` is a `Vehicle` but you can't add `Scooter` which is also a `Vehicle` to `Set<Car>` but `Set<Vehicle>` may have `Car`,`Bike`,`Scooter` etc. but you can't add other vehicles in `Set<Car>`.

Answer (score 0):

`Set<AImpl>` to `Set<A>` , your  `Set<AImpl>` is of type `AImpl` not `A`

```
public class BImpl implements B {
    private Set<A> p;  

    public Set<A> methodName() {
        return this.p;
    }
}
```

Change `Set<AImpl> p` to `Set<A> p` and return type of method to `Set<AImpl>`.

Answer (score 0):

`Set<A>` is different from `Set<AImpl>`.
Consider what would happen if this was possible:

```
class AImpl implements A {...}
class AImpl2 implements A {...}

Set<AImpl> aimpls = new Set<AImpl>();
Set<A> foo = aimpls;
foo.add(new AImpl2());

AImpl value = aimpls.iterator().next(); //ClassCastException - it's actually an AImpl2
```

If you're only going to be reading from `p`, then it would be safe to assign a `Set<AImpl>` to it, but in that case it should be:

```
Set<? extends A> p;
public Set<? extends A> methodName() {
    return this.p;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

First lets discuss why you are getting this error

In the class `BImpl` you have created a variable of type `Aimpl`. In the method you have return type of interface class `A`.

In the method you are trying to return a value of type `Aimpl`. However the compiler expects a return value of type `A`. That is why you are getting this error

Now how to avoid it

Change the return type of your method to `Set<Aimpl>` or declare `p` as suggested by Patryk